# ionic native http POST is not sending data to the server

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I ran into the some problem. POST is not sending data to the server. GET is working fine. Below is my code:-

```
post(user){
let bodynow = {
"email_id": "aa@gmsd.sdf",
"mobile":"9978897989",
"first_name": "dfdf",
"last_name": "ghgfh",
"user_title":"MS",
"country_code": "91"
}

const url =
"https://www.allevoyage.com/index.php/hotels_android/update_profile";
this.http.setDataSerializer("json");
this.http
.post(url, bodynow,headers)
.then(data => {
console.log(data,data.url);
})
.catch(err => {
console.log(err);
});
}
```

> Following are the version:
>   cordova-plugin-advanced-http version:-2.0.1
>   ionic-native/http version:-4.17.0
>   "cordova-ios": "4.5.5"

I'm getting proper output when i'm using postman, but when i'm using ionic native http it is not sending data to the server and i'm getting status 200, user not exist as result.
Can someone please help me with where I went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this in header "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: After putting header also its the same

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

First Import the map operator:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators/map";
```

Then the following code:

```
var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*'); //your origin
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT'); //optional
    headers.append('Accept','application/json'); //optional
    headers.append('content-type','application/json'); //set your content-type

this.http.post("https://www.allevoyage.com/index.php/hotels_android/update_profile" , bodynow, {headers: headers}).pipe(
      map(res => res.json())
).subscribe(response => {
  console.log("Response: " + response);
});
```

Comment: I'm using ionic native http plugin not the angular http

Comment: Okay otherwise i would highly recommend to use XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Is there any reason to especially use the native http plugin? Because it would work way more better with a XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You will always get a cors error when you dont set Request headers. Doesnt matter what you are using to do the post request

Comment: I have changed to angular-http, but with remote server i'm having cors issue

Comment: As I said: You will ALWAYS have a cors error. It doesnt matter if your are using native http, angular http or XMLhttpRequest. The cors error is because of the headers and/or the cors settings on your Server don't allow your Request because of your Origin

Comment: Maybe another reason: You are calling this request from your localhost. Your localhost runs http but http isnt secure. Maybe the server only allows secure requests from https